# Stack Overflow questions page no longer loads new questions

Tags: bug, status-completed, questions, search, live-refresh

I just noticed this a few hours ago: the questions is no longer loading new questions. My search query is `[javascript] or [c++]` and I have to refresh the page periodically to see new questions. There are no errors in the console (apart from cookie errors). Switching browsers didn't help. Clearing cache didn't either.

Comment: SE was having some issues with WebSockets, which are what deliver notifications of new questions and all the "live" updates to pages. The issues *appear* to be resolved at this point. If you are *still* experiencing problems after a new reload of the page, then that would be good to know.

Comment: So. This also happened to me. And it turns out it was a combination of having the cybersec option in Nord VPN turned on, the Do Not Send option in FFselected, AND tracking enabled for SO.